# Passing data in the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, variables

I'm working on an ASP.NET page (using C#) that will do relevant actions when triggering certain scripts, but here's what i want to do...

Normally i would put data through URL defining the variables and values as such...

example.test.com/test.aspx?v1=value

What I'm trying to do is send end user an URL that would contain only value part.

So the URL that I'm sending to the user would be:

example.test.com/value

Best regards,

Thank You very much in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would also suggest making your question a bit more descriptive, as it took me two or three times to understand your question.

Comment: Take a look at ASP.NET Friendly URLs for Web Forms: http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/latest/aspnet-and-web-tools-20122-release-notes-rtw#_ASP.NET_Friendly_URLs
Or switch to ASP.NET MVC

Comment: If you are using v4.0 then you can use built in asp.net webform [routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code below in your serverside FORM_LOAD code block.

```
string SentValue;
//
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  if (Request.QueryString.Count > 0) {
    SentValue = Request.QueryString.Item(0);
  } else {
    SentValue = "Nothing Doing!";
  }
}
```

When you send the data send it as follows (imagine the page your sending it to is called test.aspx)

```
<a href="test.aspx?AZAM">Data is azam</a>
<a href="test.aspx?ANISA">Data is anisa</a>
<a href="test.aspx?RAZINA">Data is razina</a>
<a href="test.aspx?RASHIDA">Data is rashida</a>
<a href="test.aspx?ALEX">Data is alex</a>
<a href="test.aspx?ANGELA">Data is angela</a>
<a href="test.aspx?PETER">Data is peter</a>
<a href="test.aspx?PAUL">Data is paul</a>
```

Comment: Thank You Zaf Khan, that's closest solution that i need. 
Netricity and RS, thank You for Your help... i will also take a look at Your proposals